# Associating Availability Sets with Load balancer NAT rule

Tags: c#, azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-availability-set

I am trying to create and configure a load balancer using (.net) management libraries for azure resource manager. Load balancer gets created and also the NAT rules. but i am not finding the way to associate the load balancer with the existing availability set (with one VM inside). I know we can do it manually from Azure Portal (ARM) by editing the created NAT rule in the load balancer settings and setting the 'Target' property. But while configuring the load balancer through .net code, i don't find the 'Target' property or something like to associate the rule with an availability set.
Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Configure it on the portal, and then investigate the template using the 'resource explorer' (also on the portal). That should give you the answer.